# Reference type initialized inside local block is uninitialized outside local block

Tags: java

In the following code, I have declared a reference type variable outside of try-catch block. Then I initialize it inside the try block and try to use it again inside final block. But the compiler is warning me about the variable being uninitialized inside the final block.

From my understand, since I've initialized the `file` variable in the try block, it shouldn't be null in the final block.

```
import java.io.*;

class test {
    public static void main (String ... args) throws IOException{    
        FileInputStream file;
        // Solution : FileInputStream file = null; 

        try {
            file = new FileInputStream("data");         
        }
        catch(IOException exc) {
            System.out.println("Error Occured!");
        }
        finally {
            file.close(); // Error : variable file might not have been initialized
        }
    }
}
```

I solved this problem by initializing file variable as null.

My question is, why after initializing a reference variable inside a try block, the variable will remain uninitialized in the final block?

---

I run into the same problem when initializing `file` variable inside a `if` statement,

```
import java.io.*;

class test{
    public static void main (String ... args) throws IOException{    
    FileInputStream file;
    // Solution : FileInputStream file = null; 

    int i = 0;
    if(i > 5){
        file = new FileInputStream("data"); 
    }

    file.close(); // Error : variable file might not have been initialized
  }
}
```

Comment: Just set it to `null` ahead of the `try` (or where it's declared).  The compiler requires that the variable be seen to be initialized along all paths, and it would not be initialized if the `try` took an exception before the assignment statement.

Comment: (You run into the same problem if the variable is only set in an `if` statement, even though later on you only reference it in another `if` statement with the identical condition.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you. So java goes over only the outer most scope first and finds a problem with a variable being used without being initialized. So I can basically break my program into two scopes, non-conditional and conditional?

Comment: Not exactly.  The compiler effectively executes the program over and over, taking a different combination of possible flows each time.  If it finds a case where a variable has not been initialized, that produces your error, even though other possible flows are OK.

Comment: @HotLicks Can you give me some references or tutorials on this topic "The compiler effectively executes the program over and over.". I'd like to read more about it.

Comment: That was a simple-minded description.  For more info look up "reaching definitions", a concept under the general category of "data flow analysis".  Every Java variable, at the point of reference (ie, reading the value) must be "assigned" along all possible paths.

Comment: @HotLicks Could you please add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that if `new FileInputStream("data")` throws, then the `file` variable will not be set from within the final block.  You can fix this by doing a catch with resources.

```
try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("data")){
}
catch(IOException exc){
    System.out.println("Error Occured!");
}
```

If you do try with resources then you will not need the final block to close the stream.... java will close it for you.

You can also just check to see if it is null before closing it in the final block.

Answer (score 0):

The error is *might be uninitialized* and it might be, if the constructor throws an `Exception` (which it might). Alternatively, you could use the [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which will `close()` for you

```
try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream("data")) {
    // ...            
}
catch(IOException exc){
    // What error.
    System.out.println("Error Occurred! " + exc.toString());
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or,

```
finally {
  if (file != null) {
    try {
      file.close();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My question was, why the initialization was missing outside of try block. Sorry for the confusion. I've updates my question for clarity.

Comment: @iamcreasy I understood that, and my answer is explaining why.